# Arithmetic operations in a list

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of integers

```
[2, 5, 6, 7...n]
```

I want to perform arithmetic operations so that;

1. the sum of each element squared is calculated, and;
2. the accumulated multiplication of each element is produced.

For eg:

1. `2*2 + 5*5 + 6*6 + 7*7+...n*n`
2. `2*5*6*7...*n`

How do i do that?

Comment: put a for loop till length of list. you will get value of each item..then perform math what you have shown in your eg:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward with a list comprehension or a loop:

```
In [1]: L = [2, 5, 6, 7]

In [2]: sum([e*e for e in L])
Out[2]: 114

In [3]: prod = 1

In [4]: for e in L:
   ...:     prod *= e
   ...:     

In [5]: prod
Out[5]: 420
```

If you're using NumPy, things are even simpler because many array operations are vectorized:

```
In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: a = np.array(L)

In [9]: a**2
Out[9]: array([ 4, 25, 36, 49])

In [10]: np.sum(a**2)
Out[10]: 114

In [11]: np.prod(a)
Out[11]: 420
```

Answer (score 3):

To sum all squares up:

```
sum(map(lambda x: x*x, [2, 5, 6, 7...n]))
```

To get the product of all items:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [2, 5, 6, 7...n])
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `reduce` instead of `filter`?

Comment: @tobias_k Argh, yes. Thanks. ;)

Comment: With Python3 you should use `functools.reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to loop through the list and perform the mathematical functions needed inside the loop and then append the result to an external variable.

```
my_list = [2,3,5,6,7,8]

square_sum_result = 0
product_result = 1
for number in mylist:
    square_sum_result += pow(number, 2)
    product_result *= number
```

This is most likely not the most efficient way though.